# Hiding soft keyboard in Custom adapter

Tags: android, listview, adapter

I am having a custom adapter for a list view in which I have edittext. Problem was when focusing the cursor to the edittext, keyboard hides the edittext.In case of Activity we can solve this by adding windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" in manifest.xml. How can we solve this in list view adapter.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, did u try below code?

copy this after onCreate of the activity:

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN);
```

OR

copy below code to the Adapter's constructor (you have to pass the context to adapter before):

```
Activity activity = (Activity)context;    activity.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN);
```

Comment: Tried both codes. While clicking on the Edittext keyboard is adjusting but once I started typing on that edit text it hiding again.